# Выбор между функцией или методом python

Tags: python, ооп

Я разрабатываю модуль для линейной алгебры, в частности для работы с матрицами. Мне надо сделать функцию определителя, которая принимает на вход массив и возвращает число, где нет преобразования объекта класса.  Надо ли впихивать её в класс матрицы, или же сделать её как обычную функцию.
Как корректней с точки зрения оформления/читаемости кода? Как это обычно делают?
Спасибо

Comment: Если у вас есть класс матрицы, то почему бы и нет. Если нет, то возможно не нужно плодить лишние сущности и обойдитесь функцией

Comment: Конечно метод. Вам в отрыве от этого класса ваша функция где-нибудь пригодится?

Comment: @vp_arth В отрыве от класса функция не нужна. Определитель вычисляется исходя из данных объекта. Метод, в отличие от функции преобразует объект, чего мне не надо.

Comment: @gil9red Да, есть класс матрицы в рамках которого и хотелось всё делать. Просто возникают сложности с тем, что метод преобразует объект, чего мне никак не надо.

Comment: Для вычисления определителя не нужно модифицировать данные)

Comment: Храните данные в матрице в кортежах. А все мутирующие методы пусть возвращают новый объект матрицы)

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо, не думал об этом. Решает проблему

Comment: @gil9red Да, вы правы, определитель как неудачный пример взял. Просто есть другие методы, которые изменяют.  В любом случае, вопрос решён. Благодарю за содействие.